# WebRequest's GetResponseAsync unstable while GetResponse isn't

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, webrequest

I'm performing many requests through a collection of URLs so I can check which ones could retrieve a PDF file.

In order to do this, I create a `WebRequest` with `HEAD` method and checking afterwards the response I get.

When I perform the `webRequest.GetResponse()` (sync) everything seems to work fine and every request is being "fired".

On the other hand, when I perform the `await webRequest.GetResponseAsync()` for the third time it simply doesn't reach the end of the method.

Since it's actually into a `try-catch` in order to handle possible unreachable hosts, it simply ignores that link.

`Async` version:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetLinksContainsDownloadablePdfAsync(IEnumerable<string> linksInMail)
{
    var downloadableLinks = new List<string>();
    foreach (var link in linksInMail)
    {
        var headRequest = WebRequest.Create(link);
        headRequest.Method = "HEAD";
        try
        {
            var responseTest = await headRequest.GetResponseAsync();
            if (responseTest.Headers["Content-Type"].Contains("application/pdf"))
                downloadableLinks.Add(link);
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            //If it's not accesible, just ignore it
        }
    }
    return downloadableLinks;
}
```

`Sync` version:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetLinksContainsDownloadablePdf(IEnumerable<string> linksInMail)
{
    var downloadableLinks = new List<string>();
    foreach (var link in linksInMail)
    {
        var headRequest = WebRequest.Create(link);
        headRequest.Method = "HEAD";
        try
        {
            var responseTest = headRequest.GetResponse();
            if (responseTest.Headers["Content-Type"].Contains("application/pdf"))
                downloadableLinks.Add(link);
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            //If it's not accesible, just ignore it
        }
    }
    return downloadableLinks;
}
```

Could anyone help throwing out some light here?

I'm not getting any `Exception` actually and the debugger isn't even reaching the `return downloadableLinks` line.

Note this is going to run in a server, so I'm specially interested to be multi-thread friendly.

**EDIT**: This method is not the only one which is `async` and I'm calling it from other `async methods`, so I'm supposed to be correctly handling the `Task` itself.

This is the method where I'm calling the `GetLinksContainsDownloadablePdfAsync` method

```
protected override async Task<IEnumerable<StoredFile>> ExtractPdfAsync(EmailMessageItem message, DocumentInfo documentInfo)
{
    var document = new HtmlDocument();
    document.LoadHtml(message.Body.HtmlBody);
    var validLinks = await new LinkHelper(document).GetValidLinksInHtmlBodyAsync();

    var pdfFiles = await DownloadPdfFromLinksAsync(documentInfo, validLinks);
    return pdfFiles;
}
```

**EDIT 2**: In order to provide more information to perform tests, these are links found on e-mails, and the e-mail I'm having issues with is an e-mail from a daily online newspaper. I've debugged every single call and noticed it's producing 3 calls since it's diverted with some redirects (3xx). [Here is a link to](https://pastebin.com/FzZVnVNX) pastebin with almost every link (removed some due to privacy-subscription issues)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `return downloadableLinks;`. Run to it. What is the value of `downloadableLinks.Count`?

Comment: are you getting an exception??

Comment: Why do your methods return Task?

Comment: @mjwills I have actually done that and the debugger simply doesn't reach that point. And no, I'm not getting any exception actually.

Comment: Have you considered using `HttpClient` instead?

Comment: Change the signature of the method to return IEnumerable<string> you're not returning any task from it.

Comment: If you want to return task the start a Task with return Task.Run(async () => { your code }

Comment: have you awaited GetLinksContainsDownloadablePdfAsync ? Please provide code that uses that method as well.

Comment: @Vladimir Yes! I've updated my question its calling method. It's called from even another `async` method but all of them are `await`

Comment: try to sniff the HTTP traffic, and see the difference.  And add more generic catch with logging. There are 2 possible reason why we don not reach return - 1 somwhere task has been launched but not awaited, some exception were thrown in `responseTest.Headers` or calling code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not properly disposing the response object. I was able to reproduce your issue with the debugger, and after a few hits it became unstable and didn't hit the next line.

I think you may be able to solve this by disposing the response before getting a new one:

```
using (var response = await headRequest.GetResponseAsync())
{
    if (response.Headers["Content-Type"].Contains("application/pdf"))
    {                            
        downloadableLinks.Add(link);
    }
}
```